# how i can add up route to netplan

Tags: ubuntu, networking

i have ubuntu 20.04

i need to add up route to netplan network

i have old files

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens160
iface ens160 inet static
   address 185.104.253.34
   netmask 255.255.255.240
   broadcast 185.104.253.47
   gateway 185.104.253.41
   dns-name servers 185.104.253.197

auto ens192
iface ens192 inet static
        address 192.168.222.7
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.222.0
        broadcast 192.168.222.255

up route add -host 224.2.90.8 dev ens192
up route add -host 224.2.90.9 dev ens192
up route add -host 224.2.90.11 dev ens192
up route add -host 224.2.90.12 dev ens192
up route add -host 224.2.90.13 dev ens192
up route add -host 224.2.90.14 dev ens192
up route add -host 224.2.90.15 dev ens192
up route add -host 224.2.90.16 dev ens192
up route add -host 224.2.90.26 dev ens192
up route add -host 224.2.90.27 dev ens192
up route add -net 224.2.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev ens192
up route add -net 224.3.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev ens192
```

new net plan

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses:
          - 185.104.253.35/28
      gateway4: 185.104.253.41
      nameservers:
        addresses : [185.104.253.197]
    ens192:
      addresses:
          - 192.168.222.59/24
  version: 2
```

Note (I use it to streaming video channels, but these settings were for the network in version 16.04)
I can't go back to version 16.04 due to code updates in all software

What is the most appropriate solution in your opinion, how can I address it

I tried to go back to interfaces
But it is not a solution

Thanks in advance